# recursive AD-Group query powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, recursion, scripting, active-directory

I'm currently developing a script that will recursively Get ADGroups that a certain ADGroup is, and I want to do it both ways up and down the tree. Mind, I don't care about membership necessarily, just want groups. I have 2 seperate scripts that accomplish just that. However, for simplicities sake I want to combine the 2 into one script, the only problem is that it won't run when I combine them. I feel that I've messed up somewhere, so below is my code:

```powershell
import-module ActiveDirectory
$ServerpathInput = read-host "Please enter the domain for which you would like to query for AD groups For example:domain.com"
New-PSDrive -Name Domain2 -PSProvider ActiveDirectory -Root "DC=domain, DC=com" -Server $ServerpathInput -Credential domain\username
cd Domain2:
$GroupName = $GroupName2 = read-Host "Enter a AD group to query"
$GroupName = $GroupName2
Function GetADGroupRecursive ($GroupName, $GroupName2) {
    $array = Get-ADGroup -Identity $GroupName -Properties Members 
    $array2 = Get-ADGroup -Identity $GroupName2 -Properties memberof
    Foreach ($item in $array, $array2)
    {
        $string = $item.Members.Value.remove(0, $item.Members.Value.IndexOf("=")+1) 
        $string2 = $item.memberof.Value.remove(0, $item.Memberof.Value.IndexOf("=")+1)
        $ReturnedName = $string.Remove($String.IndexOf(","))
        $ReturnedName2 = $string2.Remove($String2.IndexOf(","))        
        Write-Host $ReturnedName
        Write-Host $ReturnedName2        
        $GroupName = $ReturnedName
        $GroupName2 = $ReturnedName2
    }
    If (!$GroupName,!$GroupName2)    #Prevents infinite loop by exiting the loop if the variable is not populated, otherwise it loops with populated variable.
      {break}
      Else {
          GetADGroupRecursive $GroupName, $GroupName2
      }
}
GetADGroupRecursive $GroupName, $GroupName2               #Calls function
```

As you can see, it's a bit of a mess. I'm not sure as to how to proceed or if this can be done an easier way. I've researched and found quite a bit of recursive scripts to query for user membership, but not for groups. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22217497/check-if-ad-user-was-part-of-the-ad-group-which-could-be-in-its-sub-group/22224078#22224078

As well as that `GetADGroupRecursive $GroupName, $GroupName2 ` should read `GetADGroupRecursive $GroupName $GroupName2`, this is how you execute a powershell function with multiple parameters.

Comment: That script is to query for user membership in a group. I want to query for **groups only** and groups that the group is a member of, as well which groups are a member of that group.

Comment: You only need to make a trivial change to `function findUsersGroup` from question above, ie change `Get-ADUser` to `Get-ADGroup`(and rename the function so it is not a misnomer). If you get stuck I will write it up as an answer.

Comment: The problem with that script (when I edited it to Get-ADGroup is that it doesn't return groups that are members of that group. It returns groups that the group is a member of, but not members that belong to that group. I also need it to be nested, i.e. groups that the output is a group of, etc.

Comment: You can take the general recursive approach from above question and use it to implement drilling into the members of the group queried which are groups themselves. But you have to give it a shot and then post the specific issues you are faced with. Work out what's going wrong and where and SO will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use Get-ADGroupMember with -recursive

Reference:

http://ss64.com/ps/get-adgroupmember.html

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617193.aspx