# Powershell script for showing primary group

Tags: powershell

All,

I have the following which produces Users with what groups they are members of, however what i'm looking for it to do is to also show which groups they are native to  and which ones are nested groups preferably in a different column in the the csv file.  So it should read something like

UserName, native group, nested groups.

any help or assistance would be very helpful.

FYI currently running Powershell 2.0

Current Powershell Script.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Users = ForEach ($U in (Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq "True"}))
{
    $UN = Get-ADUser $U -Properties MemberOf
    $Groups = ForEach ($Group in ($UN.MemberOf))
    {
        (Get-ADGroup $Group).Name
    }
    $Groups = $Groups | Sort
    ForEach ($Group in $Groups)
    {
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Name = $UN.Name
        Group = $Group
    }
}
}
$Users | Export-CSV C:\tmp\UserMemberships.csv
```

Comment: Perhaps this can help, a recursive method of obtaining nested groups: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22217497/check-if-ad-user-was-part-of-the-ad-group-which-could-be-in-its-sub-group

Comment: Raf, Thank you for this how would i put that into my script?  or is instead of?  I need to run this on all users rather than individual ones?

Comment: You take the bits that you need, incorporate them into your script to achieve desired logic.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm totally new to powershell scripting.  I took the original script off a friend.  Any further assistance on how to incorporate what you have suggested into what i have would be very appreciated

Comment: You need to do _some of the work_ yourself, otherwise pay for a coder to knock you up a solution. Being a beginner is not an excuse for asking other people to do your job for you.